# WebScraping, PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, beautifulsoup

I've been working on a really simple script that gets the question titles from the python tag in stackoverflow and shows them in a QTextBrowser.

The application works as expected(at least at the beggining) but the Window doesn't show untill it finishes loading the webpage and the refresh button freezes the program until it loads too is there a way to fix this problem? Here's The full code:

```
#! usr/bin/env python

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
from threading import Thread

class Form(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)

        self.url = "http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python"

        self.browser = QTextBrowser() 
        self.connectionlabel = QLabel()

        self.refreshBtn = QPushButton("Refresh")
        self.refreshBtn.clicked.connect(self.get)

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.connectionlabel, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.refreshBtn, 0, 1)
        layout.addWidget(self.browser, 1, 0,1,2)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle("StackOverflow: Python")


    def get(self):
        self.browser.clear()
        self.connectionlabel.setText("Connecting.....")
        try:
            response = requests.get(self.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'lxml')

            self.connectionlabel.setText("Connected.")

            questions = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "question-hyperlink"})

            for i, questionTitle in enumerate(questions):
                try:
                    self.browser.append("\n"+str(i+1)+". "+questionTitle.text)
                except:
                    pass

        except:
            self.connectionlabel.setText("Couldn't connect.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    screen = Form()
    screen.show()
    t = Thread(screen.get)
    t.deamon = True
    t.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You must have a very slow internet connection. For me, the `get()` method only takes about one second to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UI will always freeze until the code execution is complete. In order to avoid this use multiprocessing or threading and call the blocking code in a separate process/thread. You can also use PyQT's [QThread](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qthread.html).

Comment: https://github.com/VikasNeha/Fiverr_EmailOrderScrape_PySide/blob/master/ScrapeTool.py - This uses PySide but it will be exactly same for PyQT.

Comment: I tried to add it to another thread  but i then get this error `QObject: Cannot create children for a parent that is in a different thread.
(Parent is QTextDocument(0x1b8b680), parent's thread is QThread(0x18186a0), current thread is QThread(0x7f177037e3e0)`

Comment: same code but removed the `self.get()` call in the __init__ method and did this : `if __name__ == '__main__':
 import sys
 app = QApplication(sys.argv)
 screen = Form()
 screen.show()
 p = Thread(target = screen.get)
 p.daemon = True
 p.start()
 sys.exit(app.exec_())`                                                                                            sorry can't add new lines

Comment: Please look at the example code again and try to see how to separate the functions from UI code. Check `def doScrape(self)` function specially.

Comment: Does the doScrape method ( that you imported ) have q.put ()?? If not then how do u add the result to the Queue?

Comment: Yes, you are right, the `doScrape()` method has a `q.put()` at lot of places. For starters, you can even skip the queue thing completely as well. This is just being used to update the progress.

Comment: Your solution is brilliant i never actually knew about QTimer thank you